# Changing axis scale and decimal points in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, axis

I am trying to change both the yaxis scale and the amount of decimal places. I am using `ylim()` (to change y scale) and `scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::number_format(accuracy = 0.01))` (from scale package to change the decimal points) but they wont work together. I am using `ggplot` to plot my data.

Comment: It's much easier to help if you can share sample data and any code you've tried. That saves potential answerers from having to guess what your data looks like and what output you're expecting.  <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example>

Answer (score 0):

If you use `limits` in `scale_y_continuous`, it will work.

Also you may want to use `label_number` instead of `number_format`, because, `number_format` is superseded by `label_number` as per the documentation,

> These functions are kept for backward compatibility; you should switch to label_number()/label_comma() for new code.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = drat)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(
    labels = scales::label_number(accuracy = 0.1), 
    limits = c(3, 4)
  )
```

[image]

(Using `mtcars` built-in data for demo)

Comment: Hi, this code still doesn't work. If I change 0.01 to 0.1 it remains the same because ylim is overriding scale_y_continuous

Comment: @confusedindividual, Use limits in `scale_y_continuous` ??